# Capture matched string in IOS- Matching was done by NSPREDICATE

Tags: objective-c

I have a code to match the regular expression and my string.once i execute the code the result shows that the matching is YES.

Can any one help me out in extracting the matched string alone in some other location

This is my code below

```
    (void)viewDidLoad 
    {
    NSString *string = @"@002@[00152-614[4000846555@";

    NSString *expression = @"[\-@0]{1}[0-9]{3}[\-@]{1}[\[0]{1}[0-9]{5}[\-0]{1}[0-9]{3,}[\[0]{1} [0-9\-]{7,}[@0]{1}";

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", expression];

    BOOL match = [predicate evaluateWithObject:string];

    if(match) NSLog(@"match is YES") ;

    else NSLog(@"match is NO") ;

  [super viewDidLoad];

 }
```

Thanks in advance

Regards

Praveenkumar

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 - (BOOL) validateEmail: (NSString *)candidate {
   NSString *emailRegex = @"[\-@0]{1}[0-9]{3}[\-@]{1}[\[0]{1}[0-9]{5}[\-0]{1}[0-9]{3,}[\[0]{1} [0-9\-]{7,}[@0]{1}"; 
   NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex]; 
   return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
  }
```

Comment: 1)In the above code where do you compare the regular expression with my given string


2)Where have you extracted the matched string

Thanks in advance
|Regards 
Praveenkumar

Comment: @praveenkumar u just have call this method by passing parameter of string which u want to compare with "emailRegex" string.

Comment: if u like my ans than u can accept my ans that will also helps to others.